# Firestore : how to get latest updated document from collection

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Firestore database structure]

As shown in attached image chat_test is collection name and i created documents with random name. i want to access updated document if any change happen.what query i need to write?

Here is my code.

```
firestore.collection('chat_test')
.orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
.limit(1)
.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
   //console.log('success=>',JSON.stringify(snapshot));

    snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
     firestore.collection('chat_test/'+doc.id+'/messages').orderBy('message_time', 'desc').limit(1).onSnapshot((snap) => {
        console.log(snap);
        snap.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id,doc.data());
        });
     }, (error) => {            
      console.log('error',error);
    });
    });
}, (error) => {
  console.log('error',error);
});
```

i added updated_at new key in document.is there any other way to do?

Comment: It sounds like you want to [get realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen). If you can't get that to work, update your question to show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using onSnapshot on entire collection you have to use it on document. I directly taken this from Firestore docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#top_of_page

```
db.collection("cities").doc("SF")
    .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
        console.log( " data: ", doc.data());
    });
```

Above code executes anytime document "SF" updates in collection "cities".

Comment: how to get metadata from doc? like createdTime, updatedTime?